# Using the results of a STRING_AGG function with the IN operator in a WHERE clause

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have column `children_ids` which contain PKs from a STRING_AGG function. I am trying to use this column within a `WHERE` clause with the `IN` operator to return the `total_pets` but it doesn't work. If I copy and paste the values directly into the `IN` operator the query returns the correct info, otherwise no reuslts are found.

Here are my data sets:

```
Parents
=======
id  parent_name
----------------
1   Bob and Mary
2   Mick and Jo

Children
========
id  child_name  parent_id
-------------------------
1   Eddie       1
2   Frankie     1
3   Robbie      1
4   Duncan      2
5   Rick        2
6   Jen         2

Childrens Pets
===============
id  pet_name  child_id
-------------------------
1   Puppy     1
2   Piggy     2
3   Monkey    3
4   Lamb      4
5   Tiger     5
6   Bear      6
7   Zebra     6

Expected Output
===============
parent_id  children_ids  total_pets
-----------------------------------
1          1,2,3         3
2          4,5,6         4

Current [undesired] Output
==========================
parent_id  children_ids  total_pets
-----------------------------------
1          1,2,3         0
2          4,5,6         0
```

here is the standard sql to test for yourself

```
# setup data with standardSQL
WITH `parents` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 'Bob and Mary' parent_names UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Mick and Jo'
),
`children` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 'Eddie' child_name, 1 parent_id UNION ALL     
  SELECT 2, 'Frankie', 1 UNION ALL     
  SELECT 3, 'Robbie', 1 UNION ALL     
  SELECT 4, 'Duncan', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'Rick', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 'Jen', 2
),
`childrens_pets` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 'Puppy' pet_name, 1 child_id UNION ALL     
  SELECT 2, 'Piggy', 2 UNION ALL     
  SELECT 3, 'Monkey', 3 UNION ALL     
  SELECT 4, 'Lamb', 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'Tiger', 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 'Bear', 6 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 7, 'Zebra', 6
)
```

And the query:

```
#standardSQL
select
  parent_id
  , children_ids

-- !!! This keeps returning 0 instead of the total pets for each parent based on their children
  , (
    select count(p1.id)
    from childrens_pets p1
    where cast(p1.child_id as string) in (children_ids)
  ) as total_pets
from
(
  SELECT 
    p.id as parent_id
    , (
      select string_agg(cast(c1.id as string))
      from children as c1
      where c1.parent_id = p.id
    ) as children_ids

  FROM parents as p
    join children as c
      on p.id = c.parent_id
    join childrens_pets as cp
      on cp.child_id = c.id
)
GROUP BY
  parent_id
  , children_ids
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... but is there a way to do it using the IN operator as my query ...

Just fix one line and it will work for you!

Replace

```sql
WHERE CAST(p1.child_id AS STRING) IN (children_ids)
```

with

```sql
WHERE CAST(p1.child_id AS STRING) IN (SELECT * FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(children_ids)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Huh?  This would seem to do what you want:

```
SELECT p.id as parent_id,
       string_agg(distinct cast(c.id as string)) as children_ids
       count(distinct cp.id) as num_pets
FROM parents p JOIN
     children c
     ON p.id = c.parent_id JOIN
     children_pets cp
     ON cp.child_id = c.id
GROUP BY parent_id;
```

Comment: That works, but is there a way to do it using the `IN` operator as my query is a lot more complicated than the sample data sets I posted and relies on the `children_ids`

Comment: @Coderama . . . You cannot use `IN` with a string like that.  You can aggregate into an array and use array functions instead.